# three.js orbit object around a changing axis

Tags: object, three.js, rotation, axis

I have a simple 3D object and I am able to rotate i.e., move with my left mouse button, around the centre of axis - works fine. When I pan using the right mouse button the axis also shifts, as such it no longer moves around it’s present axis.

How can I move the object around it’s current axis, no matter where I drag the object?
Below is the complete code of script.js

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var axisHelper = new THREE.AxisHelper(100);
scene.add(axisHelper);

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.y = -200;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
controls.enableZoom = true;

var keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(30, 100%, 75%)'), 1.0);
keyLight.position.set(-100, 0, 100);

var fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(240, 100%, 75%)'), 0.75);
fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100);

var backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
backLight.position.set(100, 0, -100).normalize();

scene.add(keyLight);
scene.add(fillLight);
scene.add(backLight);

var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setTexturePath('assets/');
mtlLoader.setPath('assets/');
mtlLoader.load('180319_object01.mtl', function (materials) {

    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.setPath('assets/');
    objLoader.load('180319_object01.obj', function (object) {
    object.scale.set( 200, 200, 200 );
    scene.add(object);


    object.position.x = -100;
    object.position.y = -100;
    object.position.z = 0;
    });
});

var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your camera is being moved by the controller and not the object itself, rather than update the cameras position and direction ((ie which is what the orbit controller is doing).in your render method you'll want to update position and Euler angle on the object itself to achieve the desired effect. To do this you'll want to track and update the position and angle of rotation about the (y?) Axis of the object,in the object (model) space.hope that makes sense, let me know if you need me to elaborate.

Comment: Yes, I know panning means moving the camera. Which means, I have not moved the object neither the axis. But you realise from my question, that after dragging with my right mouse button and now object is not rotating around it’s axis as before i.e., before the dragging.

You can try it here https://3dviewer.net/ simply upload and object and test it anyway. This is what I want to accomplish.

Comment: can you please include the code that is in your mouse move handler? specifically, the left/right drag code, so I can see what's going on there?

Comment: The entire main code I have already put here. It does not have any mouse handling functions. It is all the default three.js mouse functions i.e., Left Mouse will rotate/ orbit, middle scroll button will Zoom-in and out, Right Mouse button Pans the camera (i.e., object gets dragged). Since these are the default three.js functions, so there was no need for me to add any mouse functions.

Comment: after a bit of tinkering with THREE and different controller options, I would say your best bet is to manage the position and rotation of the MTL object yourself. This gives you the flexibility of changing the object's orientation and position in local or world space.

It should be fairly straightforward to do this; simply add a `mousemove` event listener to your `document` and track the mouse delta between move events. Use this mouse delta to either rotate the object around it's Y axis, or translate, depending on if the right mouse button is down.

Hope this helps!